# Twilio chatbot integration with websites

Tags: twilio, chatbot

Is there a way to integrate Twilio chatbot to be used directly from my website as a chat service?
any samples available?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You used to be able to do this with Twilio Autopilot and Twilio Programmable Chat, but now it is recommended to do this with [Twilio Flex](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/messaging/integrate-custom-chat-client).

Let me know if this helps at all!